# PG::Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When you do `rake db:migrate:up VERSION="` an error appears

```
PG::Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5454?
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

The migration in other projects are working fine

```
gem 'pg' 0.14.1

postgresql 9.3
```

How to remove the error? Where did `5454` port?

If I change the port in `postgresql.conf` can fall off the migration in other projects?

Comment: Is the port 5454 specified in the configuration file `config/database.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have changed the port in `config/database.yml`. The default port is **`5432`** as you can see in your `postgresql.conf`

```yaml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port: 5454 # Change it to 5432
```